# How to set Tasks reminders automatically enabled in Outlook 2003?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, tasks, reminder

I would need to know if it's possible to enable by default, the Tasks Reminders to be checked in Outlook 2003. I can't afford/clean reminders since that lawyer has more than a 100 of tasks/events in calendar.